# The type 'SomeService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My service recently began throwing this error.  The service builds successfully, but this error pops up when browsing the svc file.

The service is hosted on the same IIS server it has always been on.  The only changes that have been made are updating references via NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the service project was changed to target .Net 4.5 while the Host project, however, was still targetting .Net 4.0.  When I changed the host project to target .Net 4.5, I got the expected wsdl.