# The Type xx provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, wcf-data-services

Error while even browsing to `http://xxx/mysite/_vti_bin/service/service.svc`

The Type NameSpace.Classx, AssemblyName, Version=1.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found

- when I run gac /l I found exactly the assembly as on screen
- the interface NameSpace.iInterface is exactly stated in the servicecontract file
- the main NameSpace.Classx is exactly as stated
- assemblyInfo.cs has exactly the AssemblyName as stated
- I deploy this via a solution to the ISAPI/myfolder under SP so no need to change virtualdir/application settings
- Changed the project output path to /bin fom /bin/x86
- I can see that the files are deployed in the physical /ISAPI/myfolder
- Clean, delete bin and obj folders , build, deploy
- Also tried making a /bin folder under there and putting the assembly in there
- The rest service targets .Net 4.5 (as that is SP2013 required)

This is happening since yesterday, as far as I know I didn't change a thing. What DID happen since yesterday however that
that debugging the WCF Rest service no longer worksed (debug > IE opens > never jumps to Visual Studio), after a while...
this happened.

- ref: [WCF, Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found)
- ref: [The type 'SomeService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817727/the-type-someservice-provided-as-the-service-attribute-value-in-the-serviceho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly was changed to compile to x86, when setting back to 64 bits compilation, the error was resolved.